# WebSocket compression in Vert.x?

Tags: websocket, vert.x, java-websocket

Is there a way to enable WebSocket compression in Vert.x 3.x? I see it uses Netty 4, which apparently [has support for `permessage-deflate` and `deflate-frame`](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/extensions/compression/package-summary.html) compression extensions – but I see no way to enable them (or any other WebSocket extension) in Vert.x.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it’s going to be included, and enabled by default, in [Vertx 3.5.1](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/pull/2165). EDIT: the PR has not yet (as of Vertx 3.5.1) been merged and is now planned for 3.6.0.